# How to pass $filter inside link function of angular directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-filter

I need $filter inside the link function of angular directive but there is no way to pass $filter as a parameter to link function.

```
app.directive('myDirective', function($compile) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: {
      ngModel: '=',
    },
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function($scope, elem, attr, ctrl) {

    }
  };
});
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/XpnY5dq7rnl2sWXlsN4t?p=preview

How to access the $filter inside link function?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Just inject it into your actual directive function, and then it can be used throughout your directive (including your link function).

```
app.directive('myDirective', function($compile, $filter){
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
            ngModel: '=',
        },
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function($scope, elem, attr, ctrl) {
            // call $filter here as you wish

        }
    };
});
```

Just think of the link function as a private directive function that doesn't deal directly with angular's injection system. By injecting in the main directive function you are essentially saying that all internal functions can use it.

Comment: can u post a plnkr please.

Comment: Not really sure what is complex about the answer, but here is a plunker update: http://plnkr.co/edit/3RhXJN0sIDp4Ps6c5kDS?p=preview

Answer (score 4):

you need to inject the `$filter` dependency , all your custom services/factory and in-built angular providers ($timeout,$filter) should be inject as below

```
  app.directive('myDirective', ['$compile','$filter',function($compile,$filter) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: {
      ngModel: '=',
    },
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function($scope, elem, attr, ctrl) {
      console.log($filter);
    }
  };
}]);
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/JUE1F83l1BC0LTlO7cxJ?p=preview